# Making multiple calls to the same service in context xml

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a REST service which i call from my spring context file and based on the response received i can either proceed with rest of the processing or make a call again to this same service with a different uri_variable.
Below is my context file-

```
<int:chain id="Search" input-channel="inputChannel" output-channel="channel1">

<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header name="accept" value="application/xml" overwrite="true"/>
    <int:header name="Authorization" method="getAuth" ref="Auth"/>
 </int:header-enricher>

    <int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>
        <int-xml:header name="medId" xpath-expression="/MedicineFamily/medicineId/text()" evaluation-type="STRING_RESULT" />
 </int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="ServiceGateway" http-method="GET" reply-timeout="1000" 
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String" url="https://#{environment['dataservice.address']}:#{environment['dataservice.port']}/#{environment['dataservice.paths.medId']}"
    mapped-request-headers="accept,Authorization" mapped-response-headers="medId" error-handler="ErrorHandler">
    <int-http:uri-variable name="med_id" expression="headers['medId']"/>
 </int-http:outbound-gateway>

 <int:transformer  ref="PharmacyBean" method ="formMed"/>
</int:chain>
```

Here, i'm calling a data service using an Outbound gateway with a uri variable as medId received from another service call. Now based on the result of this service and processing done in the transformer, i may need to call this service again but with a different uri-variable this time.

How can i send back a different variable and call this service again with this new uri-variable?
Also, how do i call this service in a loop if i have more than one medId being returned and i want to call the service for every single one of them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a router after the gateway and route back to the gateway as needed. When multiple `medId`s, route to a splitter; if you need to reassemble the results after the splitter, use an aggregator.

In that case, you might find it easier to add a second gateway in the `splitter->http->aggregator` flow; otherwise the conditions in the router might get complex.